# Determine if a visitor has liked/followed a third-party?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, twitter

If you already Follow a company on Twitter, then that company's "Follow Us" button automatically greys out (regardless of the domain), so:

Let's say you have the Twitter handle of companies A, B, and C ... is it possible/what would it take for you to determine if User-X is following A, B, and/or C?

Same deal for Facebook "Likes".

I'm most curious if there is a way to do this WITHOUT requiring the user to give oAuth permissions (e.g. have them "Connect with Facebook").

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There *should* not be ways for doing this.

There are methods to [snoop users' browser history](http://www.contextis.com/research/white-papers/pixel-perfect-timing-attacks-html5/) and other sensitive user information, but almost all these are either browser vulnerabilities, XSS-vulnerabilities or just plain privacy violations. You ought not base anything that is meant to be sustainable on these methods, as they are likely to be either fixed and in many cases are illegal.